# Is there a Design Pattern for parsing binary data like this?

Tags: parsing, design-patterns

I'm working on parsing some input from a UDP stream. The protocol is sort of like a binary query string. It'll send a code byte that tells you how to read the following bytes. For example a code value of 1 might mean that the next 4 bytes are an int intended to be an ID, a value of 2 might mean the next 4 bytes are an int meant to be a Velocity, a value of 3 might mean a float for latitude, a value of 4 might mean the next bytes are a string with a length prepended as an int.

Is there a design pattern for parsing things with these kinds of rules? I'm sure there has to be some approach that's better than a large switch on the code value. I'm using a BinaryReader in C#, but I imagine there's a language agnostic solution.

Comment: You could use a Command or Strategy pattern along a Factory, but it depends on how you want to consume these really. What do you do after your `switch` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want Strategy Pattern.  Each Strategy instance will know how to parse it's type of data and how many bytes to consume and some kind of callback or builder object that will handle the relevant data that is read

```
interface for ReadStrategy{

  Read(Stream stream, MyObject obj);

}


class VelocityReader{

    Read(Stream stream, MyObject obj){
       //read 4 bytes as int.
       int value = stream.ReadInt32();
       myObj.setVelocity(value);
    }

}
```

You would also need a factory class that reads the first byte per record to know which strategy to use (could be implemented as a switch) or if you want to use even more patterns, add a method to the strategy to know how to recognize what its own code value is and use `Chain of Responsibility` to poll each strategy type to find the first one that can handle the code value.

Comment: Chain of Responsibility. I forgot about that one. I'll look into it.